# how to test async redux action with axios in Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, redux, axios, jestjs

I'm trying to test async redux actions, where the function below tries to fetch an API so the response is successful it returns a successful_action, otherwise a failure_action:

```
const login = (email, password) => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN,
    user: { email, password },
  }
};

const loginSuccess = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS
  }
}

const loginFailure = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_FAILURE
  }
}

const reducers = (state={}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return {...state, ...action};
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, LOGIN_SUCCESS};
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {...state, LOGIN_FAILURE};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const someFn = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(login(email, password))
  axios.get(some API)
    .then( response => dispatch(loginSuccess()))
    .catch( error => dispatch(loginFailure()))
};
```

The above func should returns (in both cases):

```
// in success case
{
  type: 'LOGIN',
  user: { email: 'test@test', password: 123 },
  LOGIN_FAILURE: 'LOGIN_FAILURE'
},
// in failure case
{
  type: 'LOGIN',
  user: { email: 'test@test', password: 123 },
  LOGIN_SUCCESS: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'
}
```

I tried different approaches but I got always 'undefined' as output with an error message:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

my test case:

```
const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middleware);
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
const store = mockStore({});

it('TEST CASE 5', () => {
    mock.onGet("...someapi").reply(200, 
      {
        ...some payload
      }
    );

    const expectedActions = [
      {
        type: 'LOGIN',
        user: { email: 'test@test', password: 123 },
        LOGIN_FAILURE: 'LOGIN_FAILURE'
      },
      {
        type: 'LOGIN',
        user: { email: 'test@test', password: 123 },
        LOGIN_SUCCESS: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'
      }
    ]

    return store.dispatch(someFn("test@test", 123)).then(() => {
      expect(response).toEqual(expectedActions)
    })
  })
```

I tried to navigate throw other similar issues on StackOverflow, but none of them helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot to return `axios.get()` in `someFn` thunk.
2. Each test case should test one situation. There are two situations in your example: login success and login failure. So, we should split them into two test cases.

I can see you are using [redux-mock-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store), please note:

> Please note that this library is designed to test the action-related logic, not the reducer-related one. In other words, it does not update the Redux store.

E.g.

`thunk.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const login = (email, password) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN',
    user: { email, password },
  };
};

const loginSuccess = (user) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    user,
  };
};

const loginFailure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE',
    user: null,
    error,
  };
};

export const someFn = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(login(email, password));
  return axios
    .get('/user', { params: { email, password } })
    .then((response) => dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data)))
    .catch((error) => dispatch(loginFailure(error.message)));
};
```

`thunk.test.ts`:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import axios from 'axios';

import { someFn } from './thunk';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

export type RootState = any;
type DispatchExts = ThunkDispatch<RootState, undefined, AnyAction>;

const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore<RootState, DispatchExts>(middleware);
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
const store = mockStore({});

beforeEach(() => {
  store.clearActions();
});
it('should login success', () => {
  const email = 'test@test';
  const password = 123;
  mock.onGet('/user', { params: { email, password } }).reply(200, {
    id: 1,
    email,
    password,
  });

  const expectedActions = [
    { type: 'LOGIN', user: { email, password } },
    { type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', user: { id: 1, email, password } },
  ];

  return store.dispatch(someFn(email, password)).then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
  });
});

test('should login failure', () => {
  const email = 'test@test';
  const password = 123;
  mock.onGet('/user', { params: { email, password } }).networkError();

  const expectedActions = [
    { type: 'LOGIN', user: { email, password } },
    { type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE', user: null, error: 'Network Error' },
  ];

  return store.dispatch(someFn(email, password)).then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75992743/thunk.test.ts (8.96 s)
  ✓ should login success (4 ms)
  ✓ should login failure (1 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 thunk.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.603 s
```